# Android applinks fetched twice

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oauth

We're developing an Android app which is using App links. This application is intercepting OAuth links, which work by intercepting a one time link. However, there's a problem: it seems that the link isn't retrieved once, but twice, and it gets retrieved before we can respond to it in my Android application.

These links are all GET requests, and in theory, should be idempotent, but in reality, they're not: they are one time use links, so retrieving them twice is not possible. And before you say "this is not how you should use GET requests": we know, but there's nothing we can do to change that.

We've experienced this behaviour on several different devices, and even when using the Android emulator, but it's unclear to us why these links are retrieved (in some cases, we see different user agents, and we thought it may be done for some pre-fetching, either caching or something else, but we can't find any references on this). Our iOS application works the same as our Android app, but doesn't experience these issues.